# SSL Handshake issue with Pymongo on Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, ssl, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Trying to connect to Azure CosmosDB mongo server results into an SSL handshake error.

I am using `Python3` and `Pymongo` to connect to my Azure CosmosDB. The connection works fine if I run the code with Python27 but causes the below error when using Python3:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json
import sys

def check_server_status(client, data):
   '''check the server status of the connected endpoint'''
   db = client.result_DB
   server_status = db.command('serverStatus')
   print('Database server status:')
   print(json.dumps(server_status, sort_keys=False, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
   coll = db.file_result
   print (coll)
   coll.insert_one(data)

def main():
    uri = "mongodb://KEY123@backend.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb"
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
    emp_rec1 = {
        "name":"Mr.Geek",
        "eid":24,
        "location":"delhi"
        }
    check_server_status(client, emp_rec1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Running this on `Python3` results into below error:

> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: SSL handshake failed:
>   backendstore.documents.azure.com:10255: [SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)

Here is my successful output when I run the same code with `Python27`:

> Database server status: {   "_t": "OKMongoResponse",   "ok": 1 }
>   Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['backend.documents.azure.com:10255'],
>   document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, ssl=True,
>   replicaset='globaldb'), u'result_DB'), u'file_result')

Comment: **VERY IMPORTANT**: several answers here suggest using `ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE` or `tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=True`. They DON'T solve the issue, but just silence the error by connecting without any certificate validation, which is insecure. If you want to do that for testing, fine, but do not, I repeat, **DO NOT USE** in production environments under any circumstance!

Answer (score 34):

On Windows you can do like this

> pip install certifi

Then use it in code:

```
import certifi
ca = certifi.where()

client = pymongo.MongoClient(
"mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.xxxxx.mongodb.net/xyzdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority", tlsCAFile=ca)
```

Comment: What does this do exactly ? I tried it, it indeed solved my problem but I am having trouble to understand what the problem was (as it happened overnight) and how this trick solves it.

Comment: MongoClient require TLS certificate for secure communication sometimes python is unable request via TLS so here we explicitly mentioning for MongoClient to request to mongodb using certifi package

Comment: Isn't it needed to add tls=true at URI?

Comment: @HimalAcharya yes if you are using certificate to authenticate

Comment: it worked for me. I was facing an issue related to ssl certificate failed. I applied this solution and it worked

Comment: Nice! Works for me with active directory on Windows

Comment: saviour! This worked! By the way, just to add that I didn't need to do this only when I was testing locally.

Comment: Don't forget to add the IP address of your test or production server to the Atlas MongoDB Network Access page

Answer (score 16):

Solved the problem with this change:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri, ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)
```

Comment: Does this just mean it doesn't use a TLS handshake? It doesn't seem like the greatest idea for something in production.

Comment: That's fine for testing and perhaps in a development scenario when you know what you're connecting to.  This isn't what I'd call a solution however.

Comment: awesome solution to `ServerSelectionTimeoutError` ! of course that this is mostly used in testing and dev propose, do not leave this solution to production!

Answer (score 11):

The section [`Troubleshooting TLS Errors`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/tls.html#troubleshooting-tls-errors) of the PyMongo offical document `TLS/SSL and PyMongo introduces the issue as below.

> TLS errors often fall into two categories, certificate verification failure or protocol version mismatch. An error message similar to the following means that OpenSSL was not able to verify the server’s certificate:
>
> `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed`
>
> This often occurs because OpenSSL does not have access to the system’s root certificates or the certificates are out of date. Linux users should ensure that they have the latest root certificate updates installed from their Linux vendor. macOS users using Python 3.6.0 or newer downloaded from python.org [may have to run a script included with python](https://bugs.python.org/issue29065#msg283984) to install root certificates:
>
> `open "/Applications/Python <YOUR PYTHON VERSION>/Install Certificates.command"`
>
> Users of older PyPy and PyPy3 portable versions may have to [set an environment variable](https://github.com/squeaky-pl/portable-pypy/issues/15) to tell OpenSSL where to find root certificates. This is easily done using the [certifi module](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/) from pypi:
>
> ```
> $ pypy -m pip install certifi
> $ export SSL_CERT_FILE=$(pypy -c "import certifi; print(certifi.where())")
> ```

You can try to follow the description above to fix your issue, which seems to be for Linux and Mac Users. On Windows, I can not reproduce your issue in Python `3.7` and `3.6`. If you have any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For anyone trying to connect through Djongo, this was the only solution that worked for me. I'm on MacOs, Django 1.3, Django 2.2 BTW

Comment: *Very important* is to open a new shell when running it the next time. I happened to stumble over another SO answer that mentioned it for Windows. Could've wasted many an hour if I missed it.

Answer (score 6):

Faced the same issue when trying to connect mongodb from Digital Ocean,
Solved by using this function with params in MongoClient:

```
def get_client(host,port,username,password,db):
      return MongoClient('mongodb://{}:{}/'.format(host,port),
                         username=username,
                         password=password,
                         authSource=db,
                         ssl=True,ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)

client = get_client("host-ip","port","username","password","db-name")
```

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you **whitelist your IP** on the MongoDb Atlas dashboard!

This was blocking me from completing the SSL handshake.

Comment: This was my issue, my webserver suddently stopped working after my Internet box change IP address.
This is the error that appeared:
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: SSL handshake failed: cluster....mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR]

Answer (score 4):

On Mac Mojave 10.14.6 , I used (PyMongo 3.10 and python 3.7), to solve:

> flask pymongo pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Execute in terminal:

```
sudo /Applications/Python\ 3.7/Install\ Certificates.command
```

If you use other python version, only change versión number (In my case, i have Python 3.7)

Answer (score 3):

```
cluster = MongoClient(
    "url",
    ssl=True,
    ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE,
)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 3):

**By default pymongo relies on the operating system’s root certificates.**

It could be that Atlas itself updated its certificates or it could be that something on your OS changed. “certificate verify failed” often occurs because OpenSSL does not have access to the system’s root certificates or the certificates are out of date. For how to troubleshoot see TLS/SSL and PyMongo — PyMongo 3.12.0 documentation 107.

pls Try :

```html
client = pymongo.MongoClient(connection, tlsCAFile=certifi.where())
```

and dont forget to install certifi

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following code to your client connection will solve the issue:

```
tls=True, tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=True

# Example 
client = MongoClient(mongo_uri, tls=True, tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Just add Current IP Address or access from anywhere to your MongoDB Cluster, it's in network access

Answer (score 0):

import ssl

Simply importing this fixed my issue. On my macbook, it worked fine on windows PC

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was faced the same issues while connecting locally python program to https://cloud.mongodb.com/ and it's perfectly working in my case,

1. whitelist your machine IP in Network Access [ https://cloud.mongodb.com/v2/5fa4ead022943073aaa5866c#/security/network/accessList]
2. follow this step's - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72841895/2685581

Complete Python-MongoDB snippet code -

```
    import certifi
    from pymongo import MongoClient


    MONGO_DB_CONNECTION = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.XXXvx6dXXX.mongodb.net/"

    client = MongoClient(MONGO_DB_CONNECTION,tlsCAFile=certifi.where())
    
    employee = {
        "id": "102",
        "name": "Peter",
        "profession": "Software Engineer"
    }
    # Get the Database name i.e stock_matrix_db
    db = client["stock_matrix_db"]
    # Get the Collection name i.e stock_matrix
    collection_name = db.stock_matrix
    for val in collection_name.find():
        print(val)

    collection_name.insert_one(employee)
    for val in collection_name.find():
        print(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using mac and none of the solution above solved the issue, what solved the issue was installing pymongo[ocsp]

```
 pip3 install pymongo[ocsp]
```

Answer (score -1):

On mac Monterey, I used pymongo 3.12.1 and virtual environment

To solve, use

```py
ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE
```

with mongodb url