# pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: SSL handshake failed

Tags: flask, pymongo

```
    pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 
    SSL handshake failed: bc.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER]
```

I am unable to find any docs on this , any help would be great

docker requirements.txt

```
    Flask==2.0.2   
    Flask-PyMongo==2.2.0
    requests==2.20.1
    pymongo[tls,srv]==4.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! I found a duplicate of this question, here is the link to it: [SSL Handshake issue with Pymongo on Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54484890/ssl-handshake-issue-with-pymongo-on-python3/54543100#54543100). Hope this helps! Have a nice day!